# How to count how many numbers in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a password reset program, which includes counting how many lowercase and uppercase are in said password. If the password is less than 8 letters or contains no uppercase or lowercase, it rejects the password, however the program crashes when there are numbers as it can not calculate how many numbers there are:

```
import time
print("Please create a new password")
password = input()
print("Re-enter your password")
password2 = input()
if password != password2:
    print("Your Passwords Do Not Match")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Please create a new password")
    password = input()
    print("Re-enter your password")
    password2 = input()
valid = 0
lower = 0
upper = 0


for c in password:
    if c.islower():
        lower += 1
    elif c.isupper():
        upper += 1
    else:
        pass

char_count = upper + lower
if char_count >= 8:
    valid += 1
    if lower >= 1:
        valid += 1
    else:
        print("Your Password Has No Lowercase Letters")
    if upper >= 1:
        valid += 1
    else:
        print("Your Password Has No Uppercase Letters")


else:
    print("Your Password Doesn't Have 8 Characters")

if valid == 3:
    print("Your Password Is Valid. Welcome")
else:
    print("Your Password Is Invalid. Sorry")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Please create a new password")
    password = input()
    print("Re-enter your password")
    password2 = input()
```

EDIT: Thanks For Your Help But My Program Works! Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the count of all digits in the password by summing a list of `1`s/`0`s, a `1` meaning the character is a digit, `0` otherwise:

```
>>> password= "134jhie92"
>>> sum([1 if c.isdigit() else 0 for c in password])
5
```

or:

```
>>> sum(map(str.isdigit, password))
5
```

This can also be done with your other parameters:

```
lower = sum(map(str.islower, password))
upper = sum(map(str.isupper, password))
nums = sum(map(str.isdigit, password))
```

Although it would make more sense to extend your `if` statement (as suggested by panatale1):

```
lower = 0
upper = 0
nums = 0

for c in password:
    if c.islower():
        lower += 1
    elif c.isupper():
        upper += 1
    elif c.isdigit():
        nums += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable called `num` and change your `for` loop:

```
for c in password:
    if c.isdigit():
        num += 1
    elif c.islower():
        lower += 1
    elif c.isupper():
        upper += 1
    else:
        pass
```